# std::function with noexcept in C++17

Tags: c++, function, c++17, noexcept

In C++17 `noexcept` [has been added to the type system](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/p0012r1.html):

```
void r1( void (*f)() noexcept ) { f(); }
void foo() { throw 1; }

int main()
{
    r1(foo);
}
```

The latest versions of GCC and Clang in C++17 mode reject the call `r1(foo)`, because `void (*)()` cannot be implicitly converted to `void (*)() noexcept`.

But with `std::function` instead:

```
#include <functional>

void r2( std::function<void() noexcept> f ) { f(); }
void foo() { throw 1; }

int main()
{
    r2(foo);
}
```

Clang accepts the program, apparently ignoring the `noexcept` specifier; and `g++` gives a strange error regarding `std::function<void() noexcept>`.

What is the correct behaviour for this second program in C++17?

Comment: If `noexcept` is now considered to be a part of the type, then `void () noexcept` is different from `void ()`, hence this is ill-formed. Not including exception specification as part of the function's signature, unlike Java, was something that I always thought C++ got wrong. Good to see that this is now being corrected.

Comment: The behavior is that it should complain about an incomplete type. `std::function` is partially specialized for `R(Args...)` only, not `R(Args...) noexcept`.

Comment: @T.C. ok, correct behaviour by g++ 7 then. Could you write that comment into an answer?

Comment: Your first snippet is invalid even in C++14: https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/except.spec#5

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`std::function`'s definition hasn't changed in the current working draft:

```
template<class T>
class function; // not defined

template<class R, class... ArgTypes>
class function<R(ArgTypes...)> {
    /* ... */
};
```

Since `void() noexcept` doesn't match the partial specialization, `std::function<void() noexcept>` is an incomplete type. Both Clang and GCC trunk diagnose this accordingly.

Comment: As best as I can tell, `std::function` has not been updated to include a partial specialization for `R(ArgTypes...) noexcept` in C++17 nor even leading into C++20. Is this something that the standards committee has ever addressed (to public knowledge about the matter)? MSVC++, GCC, and Clang all enforce the `noexcept` signature (if present) when using `target`, but you **can't** use it as part of the class template's signature. To me that seems to violate the whole notion of `noexcept` being part of the function signature. Thanks for any update/feedback on this.

Comment: [update C++23] For the record, the C++23 standard has `std::move_only_funtion`,
which offers a conditionally-`noexcept` `operator()` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/move_only_function/operator()